# Session timeout with 2 instances of Moodle (Docker Compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, moodle, bitnami

### Environment

- Debian 11
- Docker 24.0.5
- Docker Compose 2.20.2

### What I did

On a Debian 11 server I deployed two instances of Moodle using the [Bitnami Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/moodle) and Docker Compose:

- 1 instance with [Moodle 3.11.12](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/moodle/3.11.12-debian-11-r0/images/sha256-13eef7dfe9172efcdaeffde77728e7ca62e9f7fb3afa147c3d706e995fcc8ca5?context=explore)
- 1 instance with [Moodle 4.0.7](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/moodle/4.0.7/images/sha256-bc7a1f193c1ebb47b367c93c289a98f111a4651d932cc59c55c6b96cd85fffcf?context=explore)

[image]

For **Moodle 3.11** I have this `~/moodle3/docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:10.11.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - './data/mariadb:/bitnami/mariadb'
  moodle:
    image: bitnami/moodle:3.11.12-debian-11-r0
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '9012:8080' # HTTP
      - '9013:8443' # HTTPS
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=5000000000
      - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=5000000000
      - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=1000000000
      - PHP_MAX_INPUT_TIME=0
    volumes:
      - './data/moodle/data:/bitnami/moodle'
      - './data/moodle/moodledata:/bitnami/moodledata'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
```

For **Moodle 4.0.7** I have this `~/moodle4/docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:10.11.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4
      - MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - './data/mariadb:/bitnami/mariadb'
  moodle:
    image: bitnami/moodle:4.0.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '9010:8080' # HTTP
      - '9011:8443' # HTTPS
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_moodle
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=5000000000
      - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=5000000000
      - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=1000000000
      - PHP_MAX_INPUT_TIME=0
    volumes:
      - './data/moodle/data:/bitnami/moodle'
      - './data/moodle/moodledata:/bitnami/moodledata'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
```

The differences between the 2 `docker-compose.yml` are:

- `image` value of `moodle` service
- `ports` values of `moodle` service

I used the same `docker compose up -d` command to start up the services (each one in its folder).

### What happens

When I log in to Moodle4 and then log in to Moodle3, the Moodle4 session expires and some "strange" characters appear, but always the same ones (see screenshot below). I guess it's the word `user` but with incorrect encoding, as `user` is what should appear.

[image]

The same happens when the reverse process is done (when I log in to Moodle3 and then log in to Moodle4).

Furthermore, [the networks created by Docker Compose when starting a project are different](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

[image]

The **issue disappears when**:

- I only start a single instance.
- With both intances, I open the Moodles in different browsers or in incognito mode.

If anyone knows what might be happening or if they notice that I've made a mistake at some point, I would appreciate it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried running 2 separate incognito windows to avoid running into potential browser cache issues?

Comment: The truth is, I forgot to test it, but with different browsers or in incognito mode, everything works fine. I understand that if this happens, there's not much I can do with the configuration of both Moodles. I will add this detail to the original question. Thank you!